# Validar una de las dos opciones de input en formulario

Tags: javascript

El siguiente código pide al usuario su edad, si tiene un título universitario y si está en paro. Si el usuario es mayor de edad y tiene título universitario o si está en paro, este recibe una beca. Además pregunta por el nombre y el apellido para dirigirse a ella/él cuando se determina si está concedida o denegada.

Las preguntas sobre el título universitario y el desempleo deben responderse *Sí* o *No* seleccionando solo una de las dos opciones y debe ser mediante `<input type="radio">`.

El problema me surge en cómo validar las variables **degree** y **employ** otorgándoles un valor booleano para luego usarlas en el condicional del final de mi la función.

```js
function schoolarship(){
    "use strict"; 

    let beca, degree, employ;

    // let name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    // let secondName = document.getElementById("secondName").value;
    let age = document.getElementById("age").value;

    // let degree = document.getElementById("degreeY").value; 
    if (document.getElementById("degreeY").checked) {
        degree = true;
    }
  
    // let employ = document.getElementById("employed").value;
    if (document.getElementById("employed").checked){
        employ = true;
    }


    if ((age >= 18 && degree == true) || employ != true){
        beca = "concedida."
    } else {
        beca = "denegada."
    } 

    document.getElementById("resultadoBeca").innerHTML =
    document.getElementById("name").value + " " + 
    document.getElementById("secondName").value  + 
    ", tu beca ha sido " + beca;
    // `${document.getElementById("name").value} ${document.getElementById("secondName").value}, tu beca ha sido ${beca}`;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>BECA ESTUDIOS</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Bienvenido a Language School</h2>
    <h4>En Language School tenemos una beca para ti si cumples los requisitos:</h4>

    <p>Datos personales:</p>
    <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Nombre">
    <input id="secondName" type="text" placeholder="Apellidos">
    <input id="age" type="text" size="3em" min="14" max="101" placeholder="Edad">
    
    <p>¿Tienes título universitario?</p>
    <input id="degreeY" name="haveDegree" type="radio" value="true"><label>Sí</label>
    <input id="degreeN" name="haveDegree" type="radio" value="false"><label>No</label>
    
    <p>¿Estás inscrito en el SEPE?</p>
    <input id="unemployed" name="haveJob" type="radio" value="true"><label>Sí</label>
    <input id="employed" name="haveJob" type="radio" value="talse"><label>No</label>

    <p><input type="button" onclick="schoolarship()" value="¿Concesión Beca?"></p>
    
    <p id="resultadoBeca"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

NOTA: Por algún motivo, en VSCode no funciona, pero al ejecutarlo aquí sí...

Comment: ¿Podrías explicarte más detalladamente al decir "en VSCode no funciona"? ¿Cómo lo estás testeando?

Answer (score 0):

Agrega estas lineas y listo

```
if (document.getElementById("degreeN").checked) {
    degree = false;
}
if (document.getElementById("employed").checked){
    employ = true;
}
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Beinvenido a SO en español!  Llevas dos respuestas, y en ninguna has puesto explicación. Aqui no damos el pescado, que tambien, sino que miramos tambien de enseñar a pescar y que cualquiera pueda entender las respuestas. Para ello las explicamos, al menos mínimamente, y no solo pegamos el código que nos funciona y ya. Léete [cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) y aplícalo para que tus respuestas sean mejor aceptadas por la comunidad, gracias. Si no es probable que tu respuesta sea [votada negativamente](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2882/263200).

Comment: Agregarlas... ¿dónde?, ¿en mi HTML?, ¿JS?, ¿En qué punto del JS?
Gracias por la intención de ayudar, pero como te dicen los compañeros arriba, enseña a pescar ;)